# Render page on user selecting a font from a list - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to write a code where a list will be shown to the user, the user can select any font from the list, on choosing a font, the content of the page will be rendered with that font face !
*dont know how to do that :(*

Comment: Do you know about the CSS `font-family` and `font` properties.  Look it up, that's the core of it, the rest is just jquery bookkeeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend writting your CSS like this:

```
body.arial {font-family:arial;}
body.tahoma {font-family:tahoma;}
```

and then just use JavaScript to change the body's class when the user selects the font.

```
$(document.body)[0].className=SelectedFont;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#changeFont").change(function(){
$("*").css("font-family",this.value);
});
```

Change font is a dropdown like this

```
<select id='changeFont'>
   <option value='Arial'>Arial</option>
    ......
</select>
```

Comment: @sourav if the answer of super & shad is useful to you . Then give him an up vote & accept it